# how to upgrade from joomla 3.0 to 3,1 in ubuntu

Tags: forms, joomla, upgrade, joomla-extensions

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgJmUo3BtrQ) to create forms in joomla. for this, I had to download sourcerer (which enable you to place php and html right into your content), but when I installed it, I got this error in joomla extension manager :

> This extension is no longer supported on Joomla! 3.0.1. Please update
>   to a more recent version of Joomla!: v3.1.0 or higher.

I appreciate if someone could tell me how to upgrade joomla 3.0 to 3.1 in ubuntu 12.04.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the 1 click update feature that is built into Joomla.

In the Joomla backend go to **Components** >> **Joomla! Update**

On this page it should show you an available update. More information about this can be found at the following link:

[http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2:Upgrading_from_an_existing_version](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2%3aUpgrading_from_an_existing_version)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I just found it0, It was much easier than I thought! For those who might not seen it like me:
it is in joomla backend, Dashboard page --> update now! (in my case in was from 3.0 to 3.2)